# .xsd comments in xsd.exe generated wrapper class

Tags: c#, xsd, code-generation, xsd.exe

I have an xsd file in my csproj, from which xsd.exe generates a wrapper cs file.

I'd like to comment the xsd file in a way, that the comments are also inserted into the generated wrapper class, so VS intellisense can be used effectively.

Is this possible using xsd.exe?

Answer (score 3):

Apparently this seems to be not [possible with xsd.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-2.0/c5d2507f(v=vs.80)):

> When generating source code from an XML Schema document,
> Xsd.exe ignores the `<appinfo>` element and its contents.
> The same is true for the parent of the `<appinfo>` element, `<annotation>`.

I tried and I didn't find any way to force xsd.exe to spit out any documentation contained in the schema.

---

**UPDATE**

I will try out [XsdDataContractImporter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.xsddatacontractimporter?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8) - maybe this offers more control over code generation from xsd schema.